# YAML to data storage

Tags: sql, yaml

Can I use YML file-flat system to data storage instead of SQL? I need to storage sensitive data, like
monetary values.

Answer (score 0):

In general, YAML can be used in a single-processing system. If you are considering secure storage for a web server, which is multithreaded, YAML would not be appropriate unless you allocated a new YAML file with a guaranteed unique name, perhaps using a GUID.

Then you would have many plaintext files containing sensitive data on a web server. That is inherently insecure. I do not recommend storing sensitive data in plaintext.

Databases have been used to store monetary values for decades. For example, banks use databases for nearly everything. Unclear why your use case might be different.